# Parse a string and assign it to different char

Tags: c, string, parsing, cs50

I want to parse a string into a note and octave. For example if the user inputs "A#4", (A#)-note that will be stored in (char n) and (4)- octave that will be stored in (char o). Why am I getting blanked line instead of 4 as output after A#?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    string src = get_string();
    char *n;
    char *o;
    char *note = "ABCDEFG#b";
    char *octave = "12345678";

    o = strtok(src, note);
    n = strtok(src, octave);

    printf("%s\n", n);
    printf("%s\n", o);
}
```

Output:

```
A#
```

Can you please point to error and suggest a solution?

Comment: `man strtok` should be your friend. I'm sorry, but the C standard library comes with a nice documentation. I will gladly help you, but please first RTFM...

Comment: There should be many resources, references and examples on how to use `strtok` if you search a little. You need it because you don't use it correctly. In fact, you should not really use it *at all* since it will not do what you hope it will do. Instead you should loop over the input string, and manually find where the note ends and the octave begins.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` is not the function you want to use in this instance.

When you call it, it alters the string, replacing the character that matches the deliminator with a `NUL` so you'll lose the character you're looking for as the note. The second time you call it with `src`, the string will appear empty and it won't find anything - you're meant to call it on subsequent times with the first parameter set to `NULL` so that it knows you're searching for the next token in the same string.

You might want to use `strspn` which counts the number of characters that match your set (ie `note`) or `strpbrk` that finds the first character that matches.

Or you could traverse the string yourself and use `strchr` like this

```
char *pos;

for(pos=src;*pos!='\0';pos++)
  {
  if(strchr(note,*pos))
    {
    // *pos is a note character
    }
  }
```

Whatever you use, you'll need to build a new string based on your results as the original string won't have space to put `NUL` terminators inside to separate out the two parts you're looking for.